# Sql Injection : want to show a demo of sql injection

Tags: java, servlets, sql-injection

I want to show a attack of sql injection in which when user fill a user login form and submit to java servlet. in login and password filed how we are type a query which is update any other record. I know all column and table names. 
for example I am write this query in servlet :

`select userid,username from accountinfo where userid='testid' and pass='1234';
update accountinfo set emailid='aar@r.com' where  userid='testid2';`

but its give Sql Exception how to solve this issue.

Comment: What is the exception code displayed?

Comment: So you want solution to SQL Exception / or you need how to inject sql hack ?

Comment: You've got Sql Exception probably because the sql is invalid. You need to inject the string into query that will create valid query.

Comment: I think he wants to solve his exception

Comment: possible duplicate of [XKCD SQL injection - please explain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)

Answer (score 1):

Try a single query first:

```
select userid, username
from accountinfo
where userid='-' and pass='-'
union
select userid, pass
from accountinfo
where userid like 'adm%'
```

If that gives no exception, present first the query of system tables, and then the above query. Pick an injection of an SQL update for the `update accountinfo`.